# How to clear buffers in OpenCL 1.2 c++

Tags: opencl

In my program, after calculations, there is a lot of memory left that is not cleared and is stored just like that. It is necessary to clear the buffer memory. What command can this be done in C ++?

```
Buffer myBuffer = Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, count * sizeof(double));
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(myBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, count * sizeof(double), openF);
```

Answer (score 1):

[clEnqueueFillBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueFillBuffer.html)

But TBH i don't quite understand why you need it *after* the calculation. It's usually done *before* calculation, after it you just release the buffer.

Comment: My program has a memory leak. And I think that most likely, I do not release buffers

Comment: If your program has a memory leak, consider fixing the memory leak instead of working around it. Tools like oclgrind (see https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind/releases) can be very helpful for this sort of debugging.

Comment: Here's an example.                                                                                           
uint32_t zeroOut = 0;
clEnqueueFillBuffer(queue, myBuffer, &zeroOut, sizeof(uint32_t), 0, sizeof(uint32_t) * (myBufferLen), 0, NULL, NULL);